# Using Idle with Imap_tools and Yahoo

Tags: python, imap, yahoo-mail, imap-tools

I am trying to test the idle functionality of `imap_tools` on my Yahoo mailbox. I have gone through the steps to allow third party apps, etc but I keep getting an error (included below).

I am using the example given on Github.

Is this an error in the library or does Yahoo not support idling?

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

# waiting for updates 60 sec, print unseen immediately if any update
with MailBox('imap.mail.yahoo.com').login('acc', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    responses = mailbox.idle.wait(timeout=60)
    if responses:
        for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(seen=False)):
            print(msg.date, msg.subject)
    else:
        print('no updates in 60 sec')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:*****", line 11, in <module>
    mailbox.idle.start()
  File "C:*****", line 54, in start
    check_command_status((result, 'IDLE start'), MailboxTaggedResponseError, expected=None)
  File "C:*****", line 45, in check_command_status
    raise exception(command_result=command_result, expected=expected)
imap_tools.errors.MailboxTaggedResponseError: Response status "None" expected, but "b'FMAK3 BAD [CLIENTBUG] ID Command arguments invalid'" received. Data: IDLE start
```

Comment: more examples: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/blob/master/examples/idle.py

Answer (score 3):

Last time I checked, Yahoo didn’t support IMAP IDLE.  Make sure you check the `CAPABILITIES` response before using extended features.

It appears the server has interpreted the `IDLE` command as the `ID` command, lending further credence that it does not support it.

From previous experience, Yahoo really does not want people using long lived connections: they want people to log in, fetch their new email, and log off.    You will have to poll with Yahoo. They will not even let you hold open a connection for more than a minute or two.

Comment: Right - https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/blob/master/tests/test_idle.py

Comment: Thanks. @Vladimir. I've done some more digging and it seems that Yahoo does support Idle. Here's a link to the section of the docs: https://senders.yahooinc.com/developer/documentation#imap-features-idle. I've tried the other examples but still get errors.

Comment: They may only support IDLE for certain customers, or customers using OAUTH2.  What does your capability response return after login?